Como configurar CORS no NEXT.JS com uso de API RESTFUL
Bom dia!
Estou enfrentando um problema em meu projeto Next.JS que está me impedindo de avançar com meu projeto. A rota que eu criei para login não está sendo executada, retornando o erro 403 (Não tem autorização), sendo que o CORS está confugurado no Spring Boot conforme código abaixo:
Arquivo Cors.config:
package com.example.tcc.controller;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class CorsConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("*") // Permitir solicitações de qualquer origem
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE") // Permitir os métodos HTTP especificados
                .allowedHeaders("*"); // Permitir todos os cabeçalhos
    }

}

E assim está o meu componente react:
'use client';

import React, { useState } from "react";
import axiosInstance from '../service/axiosConfig';
import styles from "./logincard.module.css";
import { VerificaSenha } from "./FormVerification";
import { VerificaEmail } from "./FormVerification";
import { VerificaEmailNew } from "./FormVerification";
import { VerificaSenhaNew } from "./FormVerification";

const LoginCard = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [senha, setSenha] = useState("");
  const [usuario, setUsuario] = useState("");
  const [novasenha, setNovaSenha] = useState("");
  const [novasenha2, setNovaSenha2] = useState("");
  const [showPopup, setShowPopup] = useState(false);

  const submitForm = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (VerificaEmail() && VerificaSenha()) {
      handleSubmit(event);
    }
  }


  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const data = {
      usuario: email,
      senha: senha
    };

    console.log(data);

    try {
      const response = await axiosInstance.post('/api/auth', data);
      console.log('Dados enviados com sucesso!', response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Erro ao enviar dados:', error);
    }
  };

  const submitNewPassword = async (event) => {
    const email = document.getElementById('username_new');
    const senha = document.getElementById('newPassword');
    const senha2 = document.getElementById('confirmPassword');
    const erro = document.getElementById("span.senha.new.new")
  
    event.preventDefault();
    if (VerificaEmailNew() && VerificaSenhaNew() && senha.value === senha2.value) {
      handleRecuperarSenha(event);
    }else{
      erro.style.display = "block"
    }
  }

  const handleRecuperarSenha = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const data = {
      username: usuario,
      password: novasenha,
      confirm_password: novasenha2
    };

    console.log(data);

    try {
      const response = await axiosInstance.post('/forgot-password', data);
      console.log('Dados enviados com sucesso!', response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Erro ao enviar dados:', error);
    }
  };


  return (
    <div>
      <div className={styles.container_degrade}>
        <div className={styles.container_login}>
          <div className={styles.container_image}></div>

          <div className={styles.container_input}>
            <h1>Entre na sua conta</h1>

            <form onSubmit={submitForm} id="loginform">
              <label htmlFor="usuario">Email</label><br />
              <input id="usuario" type="text" value={email} onInput={VerificaEmail} onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)} />
              <span id="span.user">Digite um email válido</span>

              <br />
              <label htmlFor="senha">Senha</label><br />
              <input id="senha" type="password" value={senha} onInput={VerificaSenha} onChange={e => setSenha(e.target.value)} />
              <span id="span.senha">A senha deve ter, no mínimo, 6 caracteres.</span>
              <input type="submit" value="Entrar" />
              <button type="button" className={styles.container_input_button}>Cadastre-se</button>
              <span>Preencha todos os campos.</span>
              <div>
                <button onClick={() => setShowPopup(true)}>Esqueci a senha</button>

                {showPopup ? (
                  <div className={styles.popup}>
                    <div className={styles.popup_inner}>
                      <form onSubmit={submitNewPassword} id="loginform">
                        <label htmlFor="username">Email</label><br />
                        <input id="username_new" type="text" onChange={e => setUsuario(e.target.value) } onInput={VerificaEmailNew} />
                        <span id="span.user.new">Digite um email válido</span>

                        <br />
                        <label htmlFor="newPassword">Nova Senha</label><br />
                        <input id="newPassword" type="password" onChange={e => setNovaSenha(e.target.value)} onInput={VerificaSenhaNew} />
                        <span id="span.senha.new">Digite uma senha válida</span>
                        
                        <br />
                        <label htmlFor="confirmPassword">Confirme a Nova Senha</label><br />
                        <input id="confirmPassword" type="password" onChange={e => setNovaSenha2(e.target.value)}  onInput={VerificaSenhaNew}/>
                        <span id="span.senha.new.new">As senhas não são iguais.</span>

                        <br />
                        <button type="submit">Gerar nova senha</button>
                      </form>
                      <button onClick={() => setShowPopup(false)}>Fechar</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                ) : null}
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default LoginCard;

Estranho pois a rota de "esqueci a senha" e de registro funcionam perfeitamente.
Tentei de várias formas configruar o CORS no front, mas nenhuma que realmente é efetiva. Acho que o problema é no front, não na API (pois pelo o que parece ela já está configurada).
